# Checking and updating passwords with passport-local and bcrypt in node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, bcrypt, passport.js

I'm getting an `[Error: data and hash arguments required]` error when trying to verify a user's existing password within my node app. The context is that I ask my user to verify their existing password prior to changing it within the user profile page. My stack is node + mondodb (via mongoose) using passport-local with bcrypt.

The relevant code is:

```
// code trying to match that returns the aforementioned error
req.user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    if (isMatch) {
        console.log('passwords match');
        // now save new password

        // Password verification
        userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
            bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err) return cb(err);
                cb(null, isMatch);
            });
        };
    }
}
```

`req.user` references the current user object, and `req.body.password' is the password obtained from the user's POST. I am using the UserSchema, passport strategy and Bcrypt configuration from the passport-local example [here.](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/express3-mongoose/app.js)

Can someone provide guidance on how to verify that the passwords match prior to updating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So `bcrypt.compare` is complaining that one of the arguments, either `data` or `hash` are missing. So that implies perhaps `this.password` is returning `null` or `undefined`. Check your database record for that user and be sure it has a valid hash stored.